# UIView animation does not work after a keyboard notification

Tags: ios, swift, animation

When iOS device rotates and keyboard is up, NotificationCenter sends a UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame-notification. I'm trying to start a custom animation at that point. It does not work.

I'm trying to start a layout constrain animation, but I can't use any custom animation duration, because it's somehow overridden by the system. I will always get a constant duration that matches the keyboard moving up/down-animation. How can I use my own animation duration in this situation.

Below is the code example of my desired behaviour:

```
@objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue


        self.textFieldBottomContstrain.constant = -keyboardFrame.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: myOwnDuration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
}
```

**Update**

After some testing I found a really easy solution, although it feels a bit hacky to me.

But anyway adding just two lines of code before the UIView.animate-block seems to reset the automatic animation parameters and my own parameters work again. Here's my working addition:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

**Update 2**

Best solution offered by matt. There is a proper way to override the original animation duration set by runtime: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622434-overrideinheritedduration

Comment: Thank's for clarification, although you didn't offer any solution to my original question. It seems that my updated solution will work as I wanted.

Comment: OK I've now given a fuller explanation with actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when `keyboardWillChange` is called, you are *already* inside an animation block which you cannot see, supplied by the runtime to animate the movement of the keyboard. Therefore:

- You do not *need* to say `UIView.animate`, because anything you do here that is animatable will already be animated.
- If you *do* say `UIView.animate`, your `duration` will be ignored because it is inherited from the surrounding implicit animation block — unless you add the `option` to turn off that inheritance: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622434-overrideinheritedduration
- You should not touch the position of `self.view`; it isn't your view. If you need to slide the interface while the keyboard is present, give `self.view` a full subview and slide that.

Comment: Interesting. Wish I knew this before. Most of the examples in every tutorial about animating along with moving keyboard ignores this fact. Do you know if my own found solution (disabling and then enabling animations) does the same as your proper way to turn off that inheritance?

Comment: It might, but using the `overrideInheritedDuration` option is the correct way. See if it works, and if so, use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
            self.view.layoutSubviews()

        }, completion: {(value: Bool) in
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you this approach.

1) Add struct:

```
struct HeightStruct {
    var height: CGFloat
}
```

2) Add variable:

```
var heightStruct: HeightStruct = .init(height: 0)
```

3) Observer method:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.heightStruct.height = keyboardHeight
            self.changeTextFieldPosition()
        }

    }
}
```

4) Add `changeTextFieldPosition` method:

```
func changeTextFieldPosition() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
        self. textFieldBottomContstrain.constant = - self.heightStruct.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

It looks ugly, but it works.

Comment: I'll try this at some point, but I think I'll stick with my own solution for time being (See my updated post).

Answer (score -1):

**1. Register keyboard Hide and Show Notification in you viewDidLoad()**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
 #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: 
 .UIKeyboardWillShow , object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide 
, object: nil)
```

**2. Called when keyboard hide and show**

```
@objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    adjustInsetForKeyBoards(show: true, notification: notification)
}

@objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
    adjustInsetForKeyBoards(show: false, notification: notification)
}
```

**3. Your logic to show and hide the keyboard with animation**

```
func adjustInsetForKeyBoards(show: Bool, notification: NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]
    let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 1.0,
        animations: {
            let adjustment = (keyboardFrame.height * (show ? 1 : -1)) + 20
            self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom += adjustment
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += adjustment
    },
        completion: nil)

}
```

Hope this will work fine for you.

Comment: I think this is an example of code, where the whole animation block is unnecessary  -> Your 1s duration has no effect. You can have any animation duration value there you want but the system still uses the default keyboard animation value (0.7 in this case).